# MySQL case statement using sub-select values

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if the following query can be rewritten so that the column "end_value" returns "isequal", "isless" or "isgreater" depending on the values from the other two dynamic columns.

```
SELECT
  (SELECT cat_id FROM catA WHERE uid = 111) AS user_value,
  (SELECT cat_id FROM catB WHERE oid = 222) AS set_value,
  CASE
    WHEN user_value = set_value THEN 'isequal'
    WHEN user_value < set_value THEN 'isless'
    WHEN user_value > set_value THEN 'isgreater'
  END AS end_value
```

MySQL currently complains "Unknown column 'user_value' in 'field list'". Is something like this doable?

Thanks

Comment: User_value is the name of your subselect, not the name of a column! So you have to use user_value.cat_id=set_value.cat_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT  catA.cat_id AS user_value, catB.cat_id AS set_value,
        CASE
            WHEN catA.cat_id = catB.cat_id THEN 'isequal'
            WHEN catA.cat_id < catB.cat_id THEN 'isless'
            WHEN catA.cat_id > catB.cat_id THEN 'isgreater'
          END AS end_value
FROM catA, catB
WHERE catA.uid = 111
  AND catB.oid = 222
```

Comment: That seemed to work, though I needed to run "SET sql_mode = '';" command before because MySQL is set to sql_mode=only_full_group_by by default and it didn't like the query in that mode. Thanks for the help.